# Bad file descriptor after recursive function to open file in C

Tags: c, recursion, fopen, descriptor, fputs

I want to do a error check in a `openFile` Function in C and on errno:2 I want to recursivly call again the same function.

I don't get the right answer, if I want to do fputs() after opened the file I get a Error (Bad file descriptor)

Here is my code:

```
void openFile(FILE **fstream, char* path, char* mode) {
    *fstream = fopen(path, mode);
    if(*fstream == NULL) {
        printf("\nError number %2d : ",errno);
        perror("Error opening file: ");
        switch (errno) {
            case 2:
                printf("Creating file %s now...\n", path);
                *fstream = fopen(path, "a+");     //Creating file in append-mode
                if (fstream == NULL) {
                    perror("Couldn't open the file!\nError");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fclose(*fstream);                 //Closing filestream
                openFile(fstream, path, mode);    //Recursive call of openFile() to re-open in read-mode
                /* freopen(path,mode,fstream) */  //Doesn't work either
                break;
            default:
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
        }
    } else if (*fstream != NULL) {
        printf("Successfully opened %s\n", path);
    }
}
```

The call:

```
   openFile(&fp, path,"r");
   if (fputs("blabla\nblabla\n",fp) == EOF) {
     perror("Unable to write file with fputs()"); 
   }
```

What I'm doing wrong? I think it's at the point of the recursive call of the function, but what I have to do here? I don't get it..

Output is:

```
> .\a
Content of path: test.txt
Error number  2 : Error opening file: : No such file or directory
Creating file test.txt now...
Successfully opened test.txt
Unable to write file with fputs(): Bad file descriptor
```

PS: I am a beginner with C, I've read and youtubed a lot about pointer, but I don't get the mistake.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). There's nothing saying the the error `ENOENT` *must* be equal to the value `2`. Use the symbolic named constants instead. It will also be easier to understand what error you're handling.

Comment: There is no point in passing in a pointer to `FILE*` other than to make your code more difficult to read.

Comment: @Swordfish Are you sure? C11 draft standard n1570, 7.21.3 Files: *6 The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a
FILE object need not serve in place of the original.*

Comment: @EOF I didn't say anything about copying a `FILE`. The parameter is just utterly useless and the function should return a `FILE*`.

Comment: @Swordfish In this particular case, returning the `FILE*` would indeed avoid passing a `FILE**`, however, in general it may not always be avoidable due to the restriction of a single return value of a function.

Comment: @EOF I didn't say anything about general cases either. I said it is POINTLESS in THIS case.

Comment: @Swordfish Well, I'm terribly sorry for being unable to read the invisible part of your initial comment that indicated that you were proposing to use the return value and only talking about this specific case. My bad.

Comment: @EOF I thought it would be quite clear that i was talking about the function in question.

Comment: You have `switch (errno) {
            case 2:` — that `2` should be `ENOENT` or something similar.  Don't write error numbers (`errno` values) literally; it limits the reliability and clarity of your code.  (Checking for `errno == 0` is OK, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened the file with `"r"` yet you're attempting to write. You need `"w"` instead.

Comment: Incidentally, as the man page describes, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html, write mode can automatically create the file if it doesn't exist so that obviates your `switch` and a lot of your code.

Comment: Yes, but if the file exists, the w-mode will delete it without any notification, thats why i want to handle the error